# java Regular expression matching html

Tags: java, html, regex

solution:
this works:

```
String p="<pre>[\\\\w\\\\W]*</pre>";
```

I want to match and capture the enclosing content of the <pre></pre> tag
tried the following, not working, what's wrong?

```
String p="<pre>.*</pre>";

        Matcher m=Pattern.compile(p,Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(input);
        if(m.find()){
            String g=m.group(0);
            System.out.println("g is "+g);
        }
```

Comment: Seriously, you shouldn't be parsing HTML with regular expressions. Use a library such as [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) instead.

Comment: <sigh> here we go again ... did you try a search?  how about this guidance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm

Comment: `[\\\\w\\\\W]` will match a backslash, `w` or `W`.  You probably meant `[\\w\\W]`, but you don't need to do that.  Just use the DOTALL flag, as I said in my answer.  That other trick is used a lot in JavaScript because JS has no equivalent for the DOTALL flag.

Answer (score 4):

Regex is in fact [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) the right tool for this. Use a parser. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a nice one.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element element : document.getElementsByTag("pre")) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

The `parse()` method can also take an `URL` or `File` by the way.

---

*The reason I recommend Jsoup is by the way that it is the least verbose of all HTML parsers I tried. It not only provides JavaScript like methods returning elements implementing `Iterable`, but it also supports [jQuery like selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and that was a **big** plus for me.*

Answer (score 3):

You want the DOTALL flag, not MULTILINE.  MULTILINE changes the behavior of the `^` and `$`, while DOTALL is the one that lets `.` match line separators.  You probably want to use a reluctant quantifier, too:

```
String p = "<pre>.*?</pre>";
```

Comment: If there's more than one `<pre>` element, a greedy `.*` will match from the first opening `<pre>` to the last closing `</pre>`.  The reluctant (or non-greedy) `.*?` will stop at the first closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
String stringToSearch = "H1 FOUR H1 SCORE AND SEVEN YEARS AGO OUR FATHER...";

// the case-insensitive pattern we want to search for
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("H1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);

// see if we found a match
int count = 0;
while (m.find())
    count++;

System.out.println("H1 : "+count);
```