# Get text between "tags" [b]text[/b]

Tags: php, regex

How can I get text between "tags" [b][/b] from this text?

```
Here is some
[b]
bold text [b]abcd[/b]
[/b]

and here is [b]another bold text[/b]
```

I neet to get

- bold text [b]abcd[/b]
- abcd (I will get this using recursion)
- another bold text

Please help with regular expression!

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a nice idea, how far ahead did you get to implementing it ?

Comment: Regular expressions are note suited for this problem, because of the nesting. It can't handle that.

Comment: Ikke, so not true. Greedy vs. Ungreedy matching..

Comment: Try fiddling with the text at refiddle.com.

Comment: @halfdan: Not true. Greedy/lazy doesn't do recursion which you'd need to handle nested tags!

Comment: @Ikke, a number of regex libraries have extensions (which go far beyond regular language processing) that provide recursion.

Comment: PHP, .NET and Perl regex all have recursive capabilities. See my answer for a tested and fully functional PHP solution to this question.

Comment: @Kirzilla I read that PHP 5 adopted the oniguruma regex engine, which was originally developed for Ruby. If this is true, you should be able to do it using named captures. However, for practical purposes, using a parser might be better.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Strictly speaking that's not really regular expression, but an extended version of that.

Comment: @Ikke, that's why I said "extensions" and "which go far beyond regular language processing". ;)

Comment: @eyelidlessness: So both our comments are equally true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is the wrong tool for this task. If you can control the input format, why not use proper XML:

```xml
Here is some
<b>
bold text <b>abcd</b>
</b>

and here is <b>another bold text</b>
```

and then [use an XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20parse%20xml)?

Comment: Hm, nice idea. But how xml parsers are working if it is not possible to parse nested tags with regular expressions?

Comment: @Kirzilla: [If you're not supposed to use Regular Expressions to parse HTML, then how are HTML parsers written?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/)

Comment: `Don't use RegEx to parse HTML, lest you feel the wrath!` great! Thank you.

Comment: regular expressions are not the only way of parsing text. There are other kinds of parsers to do that.

Comment: It's just a humor. :) `Don't use RegEx to parse HTML, lest you feel the wrath!` is the quote from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/

Comment: @Kirzilla: Because the XML parsers are not using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Nested structures are easily matched with the (non-[REGULAR](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html#comment_40)) recursive patterns available in PHP (i.e. `(?R)`, `(?1)`, `(?2)` etc.).  For example, the following regex matches a (possibly nested) bold BBCode tag:

```php
$re = '%\[B\]((?:(?R)|[^\[]*(?:\[(?!/?B\b)[^\[]*)*)*)\[/B\]%i';
```

The content between the `[B]..[/B]` tags is in capture group `$1`.

Those who say that it can't be done are mistaken.

The new parser I just finished for the FluxBB open source forum software uses a more advanced version of this regex. If you're interested in taking a look at it, see: [New FluxBB 2011 Parser Regular Expressions](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/fluxbb_jmr_dev/viewtopic.php?id=3). (But fair warning: this is not for the regex-faint-of-heart!)

p.s. News flash! Perl and .NET can do it too.

Comment: +1 The misunderstanding that you point out is something that I see over and over on this website. Why are people so confused about regular expressions and regular grammars? Really.