# Finding a string between 2 other strings that has a minimum length of 5 a maximum of 7 and contains 2 dots

Tags: vb.net, string

Ok, this might sound a bit complicated, but trust me it shouldn't be.

What I need to do is find a string that can be any value, and is placed between `">"` and `"</"` with a minimun length of 5 and a maximum length of 7 and contains exactly 2 dots.

So if I have a text file like this:

```
<a href="www.site.com">a site</a>
text<br />
More test<br />
<img src="maybe an images">
<h2>5.0.77</h2></br>
More text<br />
```

I want it to find only the 5.0.77. And no, the number isn't always between `h2` tags, and the number isn't even always the same. The only thing that is static about it is that is is between `">"` and `"</"` and that it is between 5 and 7 characters and contains 2 dots.

So if anyone could help, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Should this have a homework tag?

Comment: Don't think teachers are smart enough to ask questions like that ;-)

Comment: Why the _random_ tag -- are you trying to generate strings like this, or find them? One other thing -- [if you are using RE to parse HTML, you are barking up the wrong tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("<h2>5.0.77</h2>"))
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("<h2>5.77</h2>"))
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("<h1>title</h1>"))
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("<h2>1575.0.77</h2>"))
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("<h2>2.0.77</h2>"))
        Console.WriteLine(FindString("5.0.77</h2>"))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function FindString(ByVal Text As String) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(Text, ">([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)<")

        If match.Groups.Count = 2 Then
            If match.Groups(1).Value.Length >= 5 AndAlso match.Groups(1).Value.Length <= 7 Then
                result = match.Groups(1).Value
            End If
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```